# Bash, reading a file line by line with jumps

Tags: bash

I need to read a file line by line but sometimes, depends on condition, jump a number of lines.
How do I do that?

Thank you.
(sorry for my English)

Comment: Please include some code - show what you've tried and what your specific question is.

Comment: ^ What he said. Also, you are probably looking for the [`continue`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_05.html) statement.

Comment: Using the: while read line. I know of continue, but it only skips one line, sometimes I need to skip 3 lines or 2, all depends on condition.

Comment: Since there is no way to know beforehand exactly where a particular line starts, the only way to skip lines is for your code to read them each in turn and just choose not to do anything with the ones you want to skip.

Answer (score 2):

```
#! /bin/bash

function skip() {
    for (( i=0 ; i<$1; ++i )); do
        read line
    done
}

while read line; do
    if [[ "$line" == "#"* ]]; then
        skip 2
    else
        ...
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while read line
do
  echo "$line"
  if [ "$line" != "As I expect" ]; then
    echo "Jumping...";
  fi
done
```